# Converting Oracle timestamp(6) to datetime

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, oracle11g

I am pulling data in from an Oracle source (SSIS). After a week of successful run, a timestamp of '6/19/0002 12:00:00 AM' shows up. How do I convert this to SQL server datetime? I am fine with just setting this as null, but how do I detect invalid dates in ssis?

SQL Server 2008/SSIS 2012

I do not have control of Oralce source.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are probably looking for [datetime2(6)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) in SQL Server 2008.

> Defines a date that is combined with a time of day that is based on
>   24-hour clock. datetime2 can be considered as an extension of the
>   existing datetime type that has a larger date range, a larger default
>   fractional precision, **and optional user-specified precision.**